# StateMachineInterceptor fired on transient states

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

I have a transition from A -> X_choice, and X_choice will go to either B or C. I would like to have an interceptor so i can log transitions from A -> B || C. When i try to hook into any of the possible events, (preStateChanged, etc), I only get the transition going from A -> X_choice. The callbacks don't get fired when going from X_choice -> B or X_choice. Is there any way for me to easily do this?

```
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, Events> states) throws Exception {
    states.withStates()
            .initial(States.A)
            .junction(States.X_choice)
            .state(States.B)
            .state(States.C)
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, Events> transitions) throws Exception {
    transition
        .withExternal().source(States.A).target(States.X_choice).event(Events.E).and()
        .withJunction()
                .source(States.X_choice)
                .first(States.B, guard())
                .last(States.C).and()
```

And I have a StateMachinerInteceptor defined as follows:

```
    private class PersistingStateChangeInterceptor extends StateMachineInterceptorAdapter<States, Events> {
    @Override
    public void preStateChange(State<AppCfgBreatheAgain.States, AppCfgBreatheAgain.Events> state, Message<AppCfgBreatheAgain.Events> message, Transition<AppCfgBreatheAgain.States, AppCfgBreatheAgain.Events> transition, StateMachine<AppCfgBreatheAgain.States, AppCfgBreatheAgain.Events> stateMachine) {
        transition.getSource(); //A
        transition.getTarget(); //X_Choice 
    }
```

What I want is this:

```
transition.getSource(); //A
transition.getTarget(); //B
```

Or alternatively two callbacks, one going from A -> X_choice, and one from X_choice -> B. Is this feasible? I need this as I am using the Persist recipe, and the persist is actually persisting the Choice state instead of the actual terminal state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer resolved this issue in this related github ticket:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/266